# Post Order print without recursion

Tags: c

This is what i have so far. I really don't understand where i went wrong. It needs to print after it has visited the left most node and then right then print.

```
void printPostOrderIterative(BSTNode *root)
{
    BSTNode *cur;
    Stack s;
    s.top = NULL;
    Stack output;
    output.top = NULL;

    if (!root) {
        return;
    }


    push(&s, root);

    while (isEmpty(&s) != 1 ) {
        cur = s.top;
        push(&output,cur);
        pop(&s);
        if (cur->left){
            push(&s, cur->left);
        }
        if (cur->right){
            push(&s, cur->right);
        }
    }
    while (isEmpty(&output) != 1) {
        printf("%d", output.top);
        pop(&output);
    }
}
```

Currently, the code just keeps looping in the first while loop.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Just keeps looping in the first while loop @Shiven

Answer (score 0):

Here is some working code.  I had to implement an approximation to your stack code, and the BST code, but I made only very simple changes to your function.  There are arguments that I should not have had to do the creation: Stack Overflow encourages you to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two names and links for the same basic idea.

Without any major algorithmic tweaks, your code (a) completes and (b) produces the same answer as a recursive post-order print function (on one sample data set).

```
static void printPostOrderIterative(BSTNode *root)
{
    if (!root)         // Moved to avoid stack initialization before returning
        return;        // …ditto…

    Stack s;
    Stack output;
    init(&s);         // Different initialization
    init(&output);    // Different initialization
    push(&s, root);

    while (isEmpty(&s) != 1)
    {
        BSTNode *cur = top(&s);    // Different code
        push(&output, cur);
        pop(&s);
        if (cur->left)
            push(&s, cur->left);
        if (cur->right)
            push(&s, cur->right);
    }

    while (isEmpty(&output) != 1)
    {
        BSTNode *c = top(&output);  // Different code
        printf(" %d", c->data);     // Added space
        pop(&output);
    }
    putchar('\n');       // Extra code

    clean(&s);           // Extra code
    clean(&output);      // Extra code
}
```

Thus the problem is probably not in the code you show — it is more likely in the code you don't show.  My best guess is that the stack implementation is slightly faulty, but since you don't show it, it is hard to be sure.

#### Full code

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct BSTNode BSTNode;
struct BSTNode
{
    int      data;
    BSTNode *left;
    BSTNode *right;
};

typedef struct Stack
{
    size_t    size;
    size_t    top;
    BSTNode **stack;
} Stack;

static void err_syserr(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    int errnum = errno;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    if (errnum != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "(%d: %s)\n", errnum, strerror(errnum));
    exit(1);
}

static void push(Stack *sp, BSTNode *np)
{
    assert(sp != 0 && np != 0);
    if (sp->top == sp->size)
    {
        size_t n_size = (sp->size + 2) * 2;
        void  *n_data = realloc(sp->stack, n_size * sizeof(*sp->stack));
        if (n_data == 0)
            err_syserr("Out of memory (%zu bytes requested)\n",
                       n_size * sizeof(*sp->stack));
        sp->stack = n_data;
        sp->size = n_size;
    }
    sp->stack[sp->top++] = np;
}

static bool isEmpty(Stack *sp)
{
    return sp->top == 0;
}

static void pop(Stack *sp)
{
    if (!isEmpty(sp))
        sp->top--;
}

static void init(Stack *sp)
{
    sp->top = 0;
    sp->size = 0;
    sp->stack = 0;
}

static BSTNode *top(Stack *sp)
{
    if (sp->top == 0)
        return 0;
    return sp->stack[sp->top - 1];
}

static void clean(Stack *sp)
{
    while (sp->top > 0)
        free(sp->stack[--sp->top]);
    free(sp->stack);
    init(sp);
}

static BSTNode *new_node(int data)
{
    BSTNode *np = malloc(sizeof(*np));
    if (np == 0)
        err_syserr("Out of memory (%zu bytes requested)\n", sizeof(*np));
    np->data = data;
    np->left = 0;
    np->right = 0;
    return np;
}

static void printPostOrderIterative(BSTNode *root)
{
    if (!root)
        return;

    Stack s;
    Stack output;
    init(&s);         // Different initialization
    init(&output);    // Different initialization
    push(&s, root);

    while (isEmpty(&s) != 1)
    {
        BSTNode *cur = top(&s);    // Different code
        push(&output, cur);
        pop(&s);
        if (cur->left)
            push(&s, cur->left);
        if (cur->right)
            push(&s, cur->right);
    }

    while (isEmpty(&output) != 1)
    {
        BSTNode *c = top(&output);
        printf(" %d", c->data);
        pop(&output);
    }
    putchar('\n');       // Extra code

    clean(&s);           // Extra code
    clean(&output);      // Extra code
}

static void printPostOrderRecursive(BSTNode *root)
{
    if (root != 0)
    {
        printPostOrderRecursive(root->left);
        printPostOrderRecursive(root->right);
        printf(" %d", root->data);
    }
}

static void printInOrderRecursive(BSTNode *root)
{
    if (root != 0)
    {
        printInOrderRecursive(root->left);
        printf(" %d", root->data);
        printInOrderRecursive(root->right);
    }
}

static BSTNode *bst_add(BSTNode *root, int data)
{
    if (root == 0)
        root = new_node(data);
    else if (root->data > data)
        root->left = bst_add(root->left, data);
    else
        root->right = bst_add(root->right, data);
    return root;
}

static void bst_destroy(BSTNode *root)
{
    if (root != 0)
    {
        bst_destroy(root->left);
        bst_destroy(root->right);
        free(root);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int data[] =
    {
        71, 57,  4, 31, 47, 65, 69, 65, 98, 81,
        54, 58, 17, 37, 48, 64, 64, 93, 40, 22,
        45, 62, 99, 47, 18, 86, 67, 99, 68, 27,
    };
    enum { NUM_DATA = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]) };

    BSTNode *root = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_DATA; i++)
    {
        root = bst_add(root, data[i]);
        printInOrderRecursive(root);
        putchar('\n');
    }

    printPostOrderRecursive(root);
    putchar('\n');
    printPostOrderIterative(root);

    bst_destroy(root);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Sample output

```
 71
 57 71
 4 57 71
 4 31 57 71
 4 31 47 57 71
 4 31 47 57 65 71
 4 31 47 57 65 69 71
 4 31 47 57 65 65 69 71
 4 31 47 57 65 65 69 71 98
 4 31 47 57 65 65 69 71 81 98
 4 31 47 54 57 65 65 69 71 81 98
 4 31 47 54 57 58 65 65 69 71 81 98
 4 17 31 47 54 57 58 65 65 69 71 81 98
 4 17 31 37 47 54 57 58 65 65 69 71 81 98
 4 17 31 37 47 48 54 57 58 65 65 69 71 81 98
 4 17 31 37 47 48 54 57 58 64 65 65 69 71 81 98
 4 17 31 37 47 48 54 57 58 64 64 65 65 69 71 81 98
 4 17 31 37 47 48 54 57 58 64 64 65 65 69 71 81 93 98
 4 17 31 37 40 47 48 54 57 58 64 64 65 65 69 71 81 93 98
 4 17 22 31 37 40 47 48 54 57 58 64 64 65 65 69 71 81 93 98
 4 17 22 31 37 40 45 47 48 54 57 58 64 64 65 65 69 71 81 93 98
 4 17 22 31 37 40 45 47 48 54 57 58 62 64 64 65 65 69 71 81 93 98
 4 17 22 31 37 40 45 47 48 54 57 58 62 64 64 65 65 69 71 81 93 98 99
 4 17 22 31 37 40 45 47 47 48 54 57 58 62 64 64 65 65 69 71 81 93 98 99
 4 17 18 22 31 37 40 45 47 47 48 54 57 58 62 64 64 65 65 69 71 81 93 98 99
 4 17 18 22 31 37 40 45 47 47 48 54 57 58 62 64 64 65 65 69 71 81 86 93 98 99
 4 17 18 22 31 37 40 45 47 47 48 54 57 58 62 64 64 65 65 67 69 71 81 86 93 98 99
 4 17 18 22 31 37 40 45 47 47 48 54 57 58 62 64 64 65 65 67 69 71 81 86 93 98 99 99
 4 17 18 22 31 37 40 45 47 47 48 54 57 58 62 64 64 65 65 67 68 69 71 81 86 93 98 99 99
 4 17 18 22 27 31 37 40 45 47 47 48 54 57 58 62 64 64 65 65 67 68 69 71 81 86 93 98 99 99
 18 27 22 17 45 40 37 47 48 54 47 31 4 62 64 64 58 68 67 65 69 65 57 86 93 81 99 99 98 71
 18 27 22 17 45 40 37 47 48 54 47 31 4 62 64 64 58 68 67 65 69 65 57 86 93 81 99 99 98 71
```

#### Discussion

Since you used interleaved declarations and statement, you're using at least C99 so I've used `<stdbool.h>` and `bool` type. This code compiles cleanly, at least when compiled with the options (Mac OS X 10.11.4, GCC 5.3.0):

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
>     -Wold-style-definition -Werror nr-post.c -o nr-post
$
```

The code runs cleanly under [`valgrind`](https://valgrind.org/) (3.12.0-SVN).

The first lines of output are printed in-order as the tree is built up (from 30 integers from the range 0..99 generated at random). This allows me to see that the tree is built correctly from the ground up. The last two lines of output are first from `printPostOrderRecursive()`, a simple recursive implementation of post-order printing, and then from (my mild adaptation of your) `printPostOrderIterative()`.

Without your stack implementation available, I have to guess that you have a problem somewhere in there.  With a straight-forward implementation of a stack as shown (where the `top` is an index into the array of node pointers), your code is fine.  We can't tell whether you have compilation warnings you're ignoring.

Hmmm, reviewing my code, I see it doesn't check that `top()` returns a non-null pointer.  It's tempting to add an assertion, and a run-time error rather than returning null.  There are plenty of other assertions that could be added — non-null stack pointers passed to the stack functions, in particular.